# What is the difference in accuracy in answers from Definite Integration and Simpson's rule?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, simpsons-rule

I have worked out the same equation with the Definite Integration and Simpson's Rule. I now need to comment on the **accuracy** of these answers. I know Simpson's rule is an approximation, but does that make the answer from the Definite Integration a $100$% accurate? or is it just a more accurate estimation?

Answer (score 0):

If you have been able to find the definite integral, then that is the exact area required. You can then find the error in your Simpson's Rule approximation by working out the difference between your two values. The relative error is given by dividing the error by the true value; it can be expressed as a percentage or as a decimal.